# Why would Roosevelt have taken off his hat at a Jewish wedding?

Tags: minhag, wedding

Believe it or not, this question is not Purim Torah. I read the following, strange passage in *Colonel Roosevelt* by Edmund Morris (Modern Library, 2011 page 147-8) where Teddy Roosevelt is quoted as saying:

> I found I was expected to walk with the Queen on my arm and my hat in the other hand -- a piece of etiquette which reminded me of nothing with which I was previously acquainted except for a Jewish wedding on the east side of New York.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what practice he is talking about. Those of use who don't cover our heads all the time anyway put our hats *on* for things like weddings, not off. Any ideas?

Comment: What does [tag:minhag-shtus] have to do with the question?

Comment: The minhag shtus of davka uncovering your head for a Jewish ritual

Comment: How do you know it's a minhag shtus? If I ask about where I can find a certain gemara, and the answer ends up being masechet meilah, I'm not going to tag the _question_ [tag:masechet-meilah]. As of yet nothing in this question refers to the concept "minhag shtus".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13119/discussion-between-yitzchak-and-double-aa)

Comment: As hats are more commonplace than the Queen, I'd sooner assume he meant holding them than her at weddings :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He didn't say anyone walked with the queen on one arm and a hat in the opposite hand at a wedding. He said doing so reminded him of a wedding. I suspect he was referring to walking with the bride on one arm and a candle in the opposite hand, to the *chupa*, a common custom.

Comment: Was carrying a candle along a common custom back then?

Comment: Although no source is given the reasons stated do not seem to imply that candles are a recent innovation. Interesting question for the MY crowd though. http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/477334/jewish/The-Procession.htm

Comment: seems to be a old and well sourced custom with good reasons. Nitei Gavrial - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=125

Comment: Title was tongue in cheek. I thought he was referring to carrying his *hat* in the other hand while walking the kalla and was understandably confused. Good call on the candle.